# Is it possible to default helper.form_tag to False in django-cripsy-forms?

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I have started using django-cripsy-forms in a django project. I would like crispy to not print the  tag for every form, by default. I know that I can create a helper for each form and set the `helper.form_tag = False` property. However, this is cumbersome to do for all the existing forms.

Does anyone know if it possible to override the default crispy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself in similar situation. What I come up with is a mixin for views like this one below. Still I have to add this mixin to related views, but I found it better than adding `helper` to all the forms. At least I could change the default behavior for all the forms without `helper` defined.

This method only works for class-based views. If you use function-based view, you could accomplish similar behavior by adding a `prepare_form` function and call it every time you use a form in the views.

```
class CrispyFormsMixin(object):
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(CrispyFormsMixin, self).get_form(form_class)
        # Add a default helper for crispy_forms
        if not getattr(form, 'helper', None):
            form.helper = FormHelper()
            form.helper.form_tag = False
        return form
```